# Resize Listobject Table dynamically with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the size of the object tables through VBA, I tried modifying the code from MSDN about the `listobject.resize` method, but I want to dynamically if a data loaded in each row.

The code I'm trying but to no avail:

```
Sub resizedata()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ob As ListObject
    Dim Lrow1 As Long

    Lrow1 = Sheets("db_goods").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("db_goods")
    Set ob = ws.ListObjects("Table1")

    ob.Resize Range("A1" & Lrow1)

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is `Range("A1" & Lrow1)` returns a Range of `$A$112`, because you are passing the `Range` function the result of the catenation of `"A1" & "12"`.

Try replacing this line:

```
ob.Resize Range("A1" & Lrow1)
```

With this one:

```
ob.Resize ob.Range.Resize(Lrow1)
```

Answer (score 16):

There's way avoiding calculating last row:

```
Sub ResizeListDyn()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    tbl.Resize tbl.Range.CurrentRegion
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe this answer is much more helpful since I observed that .End(xlUp) will jump to the last row of the table instead of to the last row with actual content in the respective cell. Thanks btw

Comment: Not reliable in a few cases e.g. if you have empty row (no data), data above headers etc.

Answer (score 7):

If you need to resize only the row-dimension:

```
Dim tbl As ListObject

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("YourTableName")
With tbl.Range
    tbl.Resize .Resize(.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count) 'NOTE: unlike the Range.Resize proprty, the Table.Resize
                                                  'method's argument is a Range object (not a size spec).
End With
```

Resizing only the column-dimension would be symmetrical:

```
With tbl.Range
    tbl.Resize .Resize(, .CurrentRegion.Columns.Count)
End With
```