# Excel VBA resize table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm erasing and copying new data into a table and keep getting blank rows as part of the table.  Just doing a resize table doesn't work.  I have to select the cells by using `end(xlToRight)` and `end(xlDown)`.

This is what I have come up with to select the data, but I don't know how to then resize the table based on this selection.

```
Sub SelectData()

With Worksheets("data_Submit_Indv")
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Column)).Select
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried directly referencing the list object? .ListObjects("Table1").Range.Select or ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Select etc. You can use the resize method on the table.

Comment: @CaptainGrumpy the problem is that the table "thinks" it is larger than it really is so any reference to the actual table includes extra blank rows.  If I use the 1xRight and 1xDown then that selects only the actual data.  Once the data is selected I don't know how to resize the table to the selection.

Comment: Sub ResizeTable()
  rng = Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Column)).Address
  ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Resize Range(rng)
End Sub

Comment: @CaptainGrumpy  Thank you !!  That works.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize Listobject Table dynamically with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323014/resize-listobject-table-dynamically-with-vba)

Comment: Perhaps, you need `Range.CurrentRegion` property. It has the same effect as pressing `Ctrl+A` (or, more widely known, `Ctrl+*`) on a region.