# Add the row below a table to the table range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to resize a table to include the data in a row directly below the last row in a table. My current code looks like this but returns an object defined error. Also, the table changes location as rows are added both above and below it.

`tbl.resize tbl.Range.CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0)`

I have used the following sources to try and resolve this problem with no luck. [Resize Listobject Table dynamically with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323014/resize-listobject-table-dynamically-with-vba)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me

```
Sub x()

Dim tbl As ListObject

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
tbl.Resize tbl.Range.Resize(tbl.Range.Rows.Count + 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes - because `Offset` means the header row is no longer included.