# Resize Chart ListObject Automatically on PowerPoint with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, excel-charts

I want to resize a chart table in PowerPoint via VBA. I've read the following solution multiple times ([Resize Listobject Table dynamically with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323014/resize-listobject-table-dynamically-with-vba)) and it does seem precisely what I need, but for some reason (maybe because I'm running the macro from PowerPoint) it gives me the following error: Automation error (Error 440).

I plan to use the Resize method because I'm updating a PPT chart data table from another Excel file without using the .Activate method (I opted to not use the .Activate because it opened many charts workbooks after the Macro finished execution, even with multiple Waits and Excel.Application.Quit and .Close).

It works great, the charts workbooks do not flash on the screen and the values are copied fast, BUT... the table size is not correct. It only includes the 1st line of the ppt chart data table, and thus my chart is rendered incomplete.

```
 Dim Line As Range Dim financialPartner As String, financialProject As String

    financialPartner = excl.Workbooks("HNK-Status-CDAU.xlsx").Sheets("Financial").Cells(int_lin, 2)
    financialProject = excl.Workbooks("HNK-Status-CDAU.xlsx").Sheets("Financial").Cells(int_lin, 3)
    
    Dim found As Boolean
    found = False
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim financialChart As Chart
    Dim financialChartData As Range
    Dim financialChartTable As ListObject
    Dim financialChartTablews As Worksheet
            
    lastRow = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("RevenuesVolume").Chart.chartData.Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    Set financialChart = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("RevenuesVolume").Chart
    
    Set financialChartTablews = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("RevenuesVolume").Chart.chartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set financialChartTable = financialChartTablews.ListObjects("Tabela1")
    
    For Each Line In chartDataTable.DataBodyRange.Rows
        Dim lineNumber As Long
        lineNumber = Line.Row
        
        If ((Line.Columns(1) <> financialPartner) Or (Line.Columns(2) <> financialProject)) And found Then
            Exit For
        End If
        
        If (Line.Columns(1) = financialPartner) And (Line.Columns(2) = financialProject) Then
            found = True
            With financialChart.chartData
                Set financialChartData = .Workbook.Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1).Range
                financialChartData.Range("A" & lastRow).Value = chartDataWs.Cells(lineNumber, 4)
                financialChartData.Range("B" & lastRow).Value = chartDataWs.Cells(lineNumber, 5)
                financialChartData.Range("C" & lastRow).Value = chartDataWs.Cells(lineNumber, 6)
                lastRow = lastRow + 1
                financialChartTable.Resize Range("A1:C" & lastRow)
                .Workbook.Close
            End With
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the error? I have a feeling you have to open the excel workbook to be able to achieve what you want. You need to create an `Excel.Application` object. If all you're worried about the screen flickering between excel and power point, you can simply make the excel application invisible.

Comment: The line with the error is " financialChartTable.Resize Range("A1:C" & lastRow)"