# Resize Table in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which looks for rows marked x on one workbook and then if marked, opens another workbook and pastes the row(s) of data into there.

This data is in a table but I have to then manually resize the table to include the new row(s) of data.

I've been trying to add a resize into the code but I'm getting the 'Object Variable error'

```
Sub addtoconfirmdatabase()

Const WB_PATH As String = "S:\Goods Ordering\Confirmed Orders.xlsx"

Dim srcSht As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, shtDest As Worksheet, i As Long

Dim ob As ListObject

Dim Lrow1 As Long

Set srcSht = ActiveSheet

Set ob = shtDest.ListObjects("Table1")


For i = 2 To srcSht.Range("A" & srcSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If srcSht.Cells(i, 1) = "x" Then

        If shtDest Is Nothing Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=WB_PATH)
            Set shtDest = wb.Sheets("Orders Confirmed")
        End If
        srcSht.Cells(i, 2).Resize(1, 86).Copy _
                shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                ob.Resize ob.Range.Resize(Lrow1)
    End If
    If srcSht.Cells(i, 1) = "x" Then
     srcSht.Cells(i, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
    End If
     
Next i


If Not wb Is Nothing Then wb.Close True

Sheets("Quote Database").Select
Range("P1:R1").ClearContents

MsgBox "your orders have been added to the orders confirmed database."

End Sub
```

I can't find where I am going wrong

Thanks.

Comment: Where's `Lrow1` coming from? Suppose it's from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323014/resize-listobject-table-dynamically-with-vba) , they had their variable filled in :)

Comment: Yes I suppose it was, naughty me trying to find an answer myself first :)

Comment: `shtDest` is not defined.

Comment: Isn't it defined here? `shtDest As Worksheet` . I'm still very new to this, so trying to learn along the way.

Comment: You need to have a `Set shtDest = ... ` line in your code

Comment: Isn't that here? `Set shtDest = wb.Sheets("Orders Confirmed")`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you want to assign the table ("Table1") of the destination worksheet to the variable `ob` before you have opened the destination workbook and assigned the destination sheet to the variable `shtDest`.

In your code, you open the destination workbook in the loop if it is not yet opened (`If shtDest Is Nothing Then`). Just move the assignment of the table variable into the same if:

```
    If shtDest Is Nothing Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=WB_PATH)
        Set shtDest = wb.Sheets("Orders Confirmed")
        Set ob = shtDest.ListObjects("Table1")
    End If
```

Just an advice: Be consequent with your naming. You name your source sheet `srcSht` and your destination sheet `shtDest` - that's confusing. Either name them `scrSht` and `destSht` or name them `shtSrc` and `shtDest`.
Also, usually it's better not to shorten words like `source` to `src`.

And a better name for `ob` could be `destTable` (or maybe `tableDest`)